# new domain url for multi sites linked to sub domain drupal install

Tags: multi-sites

Because my drupal install is not in the root of document but in a subdomain, everything is a little more difficult for setting up multi-sites.

I found a way of adding multiple subdomains successfully to the subdomain containing drupal install but now that I am wanting to add a new domain url pointing to same IP obviously it keeps wanting to direct to document root and if I set it up in virtualhosts what happens is it makes it so you have to go to URL example.com/drupal/install.php which obviously I don't want because I want it to 'appear' as other multi-sites in the exact url not path to drupal folder.

Do I need to use a symlink for this to work? See I have two domains pointing to the ONE IP but as I have the drupal core in a SUBDOMAIN of the main IP then the second domain name doesn't want to follow the same rules as the other subdomains running off drupal core subdomain and direct from vhost to html/drupal and APPEAR in subdomain url. Rather the second name url is following the path LITERALLY and so I can never install anywhere but path to drupal folder.

So completely stuck on what to do from here. How can I make my second domain url POINT to the subdomain root drupal install and not the root of IP which is static?

Answer (score 0):

So finally figured this all out.

If like me you are weird and want to use a Sub-domain for your main drupal install and then create multi-sites from that you can just add your **virtual hosts** to the **custom conf file** or wherever you keep that.

I found that to do away with **.htaccess** in favour of the **/etc/httpd/conf.d/custom.conf file as well as httpd.conf on linux vps.**

BUT if you want to add a new domain directing to same IP it will obviously keep searching for doc root,so even if you add the Drupal folder direction in virtual host it will just go there and not install at your actual URL.

So you need to create a **symlink** in this case and then add that directive to your virtual host. so it would be something like **/var/www/html/drupal/nameofmysite.com**  which would be a **symlink** to the actual folder in **sites** folder of **subdomain.**